# pd.get_dummies wrt a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

DF Description:

Pandas DF has two columns 'ID', 'Names', where there are multiple entries of 'Names' for the same 'ID'

Use Case:

IP:

```
 ID          Names
 1           func_A
 1           tunc_B
 2           rain
 2           fire
```

Required OP:

A new DF with the entry like following

```
ID    func_A       func_B   rain fire
 1        1         1         0   0
 2        0         0         1   1
```

I tried 2 approaches using groupBy and get_dummies but I am not getting the required op. Any suggestions on how to attain this highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: See Question #9 from the dupe target.  It'll show you various ways to accomplish this  task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Names)`.

Output:

```
Names  fire  func_A  rain  tunc_B
ID
1         0       1     0       1
2         1       0     1       0
```